# the difference between I/O schedule in dmesg and queue/schedule

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I executed two commands in system, in first command, I saw five kinds I/O schedule which os system support; but in second command, there are only three choices I can switch. I'm a little confused, could you please tell me how to switch schedule to 'deadline' in /sys/block/vdb/queue/scheduler?

```
>dmesg|grep -i schedule
[    1.099428] io scheduler noop registered
[    1.100254] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    1.101232] io scheduler cfq registered
[    1.102042] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.102918] io scheduler kyber registered
[862565.814586] nr_pdflush_threads exported in /proc is scheduled for removal

>cat /sys/block/vdb/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] kyber none
```